# Visible markers in an upper-level composition in Adobe After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

In After Effects, Is it possible to have markers in a composition, and see them when that comp placed in another comp? I mean, be visible in an upper comp.

I had a .wav file which had a lot of markers in Adobe Audition, after I placed it inside a comp, it preserved all of its Audition markers as overlayed-dashed lines.

Any settings or maybe marker type required for this feature?

Comment: Markers should be on a timeline (not on a layer) to be visible in the parent comp

Comment: Video editing questions are off-topic here. Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add a marker to the composition. Deselect all layers and press <kbd>*</kbd> on the keyboard.

Once you import this composition to another composition, this marker should be visible. Only composition markers are visible. All layers markers will be invisible.